# How to create custom type for android resources value using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, resources

I have a custom resource values in eclipse.

the file name is
errors.xml

In the errors.xml, we have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="hello_1" type="errors">hello message 1</item>
    <item name="hello_2" type="errors">hello message 2</item>
    <item name="hello_3" type="errors">hello message 3</item>
</resources>
```

In eclipse, I would be able to access this resources value by
using `String errorMessage = getString(R.errors.hello_1)`

I am trying to migrate my project to Android Studio. However it's complaining about my the errors.xml resources.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Unsupported type 'errors' in file /Users/xiaowoo/project/migrate_android_studio/someapp/app/src/main/res/values/errors.xml

Android Studio just doesn't like custom type, `type="errors"`,
it allows me to set type to `string`, `colors`, `dimen`, but not `errors` (my custom type)

Is there any ways to solve this problem? Is there any walk around?

Thanks, any comments, suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, this is not going to be much help, but I can confirm that I am seeing the same thing. I think this must have been a feature of Eclipse and not of android itself, is seems there has never been such a feature. Which is a shame because it is quite nice to be able to group resources in this way.